# i want to perform a segue from the App delegate in the google sign in method

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I have implemented Google Sign in with firebase and I have run into a problem.

I am trying to perform a segue from the App delegate if the if statement is true. The if statement works but whenever I run the perform segue method I either get a signal error or a Bad Access error with the embedded message:

viewController has no segue with identifier 'Test''. The extension is for taking a substring of the email and the var up top is irrelevant. I know this question has already been asked but it did not work for me and I think it may have something to do with Google sign In. My segues name is Test. The performSegue(withIdentifier: "Wegue", sender: self) is for the initial view controller once the google sign in is called.

```
let userDefault  = UserDefaults()



func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return


    }else{
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        let str = email



        if(str == "wafster1337@gmail.com"){
            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Test", sender: self)


        }
        else{
            print("woe")


        }


        guard let authentication = user.authentication else{return}
        let crendential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: crendential) {(result, error)in
        if error == nil {
           self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedIn")
            self.userDefault.synchronize()
            self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Wegue", sender: self)

        }else {

            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "me")
            }
    }




    }


}



var window: UIWindow?




func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: [:])
}
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

}
extension String {

var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[0 ..< max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: min(length, max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is actually pretty simple and was staring me in the face the whole time

I implemented multiple segues from my initial ViewController. I then took off the email's characters that came before the domain name. Then based on the domain name I performed a certain segue.

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate{

```
let userDefault  = UserDefaults()






func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
    if let error = error{
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return


    }else{
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        let str = email
        let me = str?.count
        let int = (me!-9)
        let NewStr = str?.dropFirst(int)
        print(NewStr)




        guard let authentication = user.authentication else{return}
        let crendential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: crendential) {(result, error)in
            if error == nil {
                self.userDefault.set(true, forKey: "usersignedIn")
                self.userDefault.synchronize()
                if(NewStr == "gmail.com"){

                self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Megue", sender: self)
                }
            }else {
                self.window?.rootViewController?.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Wegue", sender: self)
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "me")
            }
        }




    }


}



var window: UIWindow?




func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Use Firebase library to configure APIs

    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    return true
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication:options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: [:])
}
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}
extension String {

```
var length: Int {
    return count
}

subscript (i: Int) -> String {
    return self[i ..< i + 1]
}

func substring(fromIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[min(fromIndex, length) ..< length]
}

func substring(toIndex: Int) -> String {
    return self[0 ..< max(0, toIndex)]
}

subscript (r: Range<Int>) -> String {
    let range = Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: max(0, min(length, r.lowerBound)),
                                        upper: min(length, max(0, r.upperBound))))
    let start = index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)
    let end = index(start, offsetBy: range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)
    return String(self[start ..< end])
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You first need to import google and firebase libraries.

```
import FirebaseAuth
import GoogleSignIn
```

**Sign in Function**

```
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error != nil {
                print("\(error)")
                return
            } else {
                // User is succesfully logged in so settting userDefaults (I wouldn't recommend doing it this way to check if user logged in!)
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "usersignedIn")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                // Now perform the segue to the viewController you want. Make sure you set the identifier the same as in the storyboard
                let VC1 = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier"))!
                self.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("\(String(describing: error))")
    }
}
```

**To dismiss and show the controller**

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**Call the login like this**

```
func googleButtonClicked() {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

Comment: So could I put my if statement right above:                                                                 let VC1 = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourIdentifier"))!
                self.present(VC1, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: If this answer helped you could you mark it as completed by clicking the check? if you have any more questions please let me know

Comment: So I implemented your changes and its giving me an error of "use of unresolved identifier self" besides the sign methods and the googleButtonClicked() metho.Also the error " Value of type 'AppDelegate' has no member 'storyboard'" besides let VC1 = (self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Test"))!. I also want to be able to send my user to different view controller based on their email so I need a if statement.